# Why i have a OBJECT PROMISE on my page when using axios.post

Tags: vue.js, promise, axios, nuxt.js

I try put result of the axios post query to dom:

```
 <v-btn fab color="#00C3EA" top right absolute class="white--text">
                            {{ getRating(tutor) }}
 </v-btn>
```

On my methods i have this:

```
async getRating(tutor) {
      let rating=0
      let lang = ''
      if (!this.language) {
         lang = this.$route.query.lang
      } else {
         lang = this.language
      }
      const rat = await this.$axios.$post('/tutors/getTutorRating.php', '{"tutor_id": '+tutor.id+', "lang": "'+lang+'"}').then((responce)=>{
        rating = responce.average_rating
      })
      console.log(rating)
      return rating
    },
```

In console log i have a number result query, in page i have [object promise]
What i must do for solve it?

Comment: `const responce= await this.$axios.$post('/tutors/getTutorRating.php', '{"tutor_id": '+tutor.id+', "lang": "'+lang+'"}');`  
  `rating = responce.average_rating`

Comment: I have same [Object Promise] result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: here is a hosted codesandbox of an axios post working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-post-example-jg4yc?file=/src/App.vue

Following by the actual snippet

```js
async testJsonPlaceholder() {
  const json = await this.axios.post(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    {
      title: "foo",
      body: "bar",
      userId: 1,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      },
    }
  );
  console.log("json", json.data);
  return json.data;
},
```

---

Depending of what your API is doing, this kind of code should work fine.
I've also written an example of how a basic post to [JSONplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/) work in `testJsonPlaceholder` method (even if it's using `fetch`, it's pretty much the same thing, just remove the `json()` part).

```html
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async getRating(tutor) {
      let lang = ''
      if (!this.language) {
        lang = this.$route.query.lang
      } else {
        lang = this.language
      }
      const response = await this.$axios.$post(
        '/tutors/getTutorRating.php',
        JSON.stringify({ tutor_id: tutor.id, lang }),
      )

      const result = response.average_rating
      console.log("rating's value here", result)
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))
      return result
    },

    // the one below is 100% working
    async testJsonPlaceholder() {
      const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          title: 'foo',
          body: 'bar',
          userId: 1,
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      })

      const json = await response.json()
      console.log('json', json)
      return json
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I've also changed the kind of string interpolation with a stringify (nvm, `axios` does it by itself apparently: https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config), doing the same stuff but easier to read.
If you don't want it, at least use [Template Litterals (es6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to have something easy to interpolate like

```js
`this is a simple string, but it's interpolated just here >> ${interpolatedHere} !`
```

Also, inspecting your network tab can help finding out where the issue is coming from !